# Errors when using npm library

Tags: angular, npm, bootstrap-4, angular-library

I've tried to create an own angular library and if I try to install from npm it throws the following Errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/abcalendar/projects/abcalendar-lib/src/lib/abcalendar-lib.module.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: C:\...\node_modules\abcalendar\projects\abcalendar-lib\src\lib\abcalendar-lib.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format (Google-Link).
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:949:23)
    at C:\...\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:43:31
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

Do you have any Ideas, where I have to search for the Error?

Thanks alot

Comment: I think it's self descriptive and guides you on what to do: abcalendar-lib.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Comment: Okay thanks.
I found out that I published the library too widely.
The following commands helped me:
ng build --prod (In the project)
cd dist (to get into the generated dist folder)
cd abcalendar-lib (to get into the abcalendar-lib folder)
npm publish (to publish only this part, and not the whole project)